# Azure IoT Hub へmosquitto_pubでメッセージを送ろうとするとエラーになります。

Tags: azure

こんにちは。

以下のような形式で、デバイスからIoT Hub へPublishするとエラーになります。

```
$ mosquitto_pub -d -q 1 --capath /etc/ssl/certs/ -V mqttv311 -p 8883 -h ●●.azure-devices.net -i dev0 -u "●●.azure-devices.net/devices/dev0/?api-version=2018-06-30" -P "SharedAccessSignature ○○" -m '{"v":1}'

Client dev0 sending CONNECT
Client dev0 received CONNACK
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Error: The connection was refused.
```

困っております。どなたかお助けください。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。

usernameが間違っていました。

(誤) -u "●●.azure-devices.net/devices/dev0/?api-version=2018-06-30"
(正) -u "●●.azure-devices.net/dev0/?api-version=2018-06-30"

Comment: 質問時と別のアカウントになっているようです。間違えて別のアカウントを作成して回答してしまった場合は、[間違えて作成したアカウントを統合・マージ・リンクする方法はありますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2092/)をご確認ください。